# Tell UglifyJS to skip a particular area of code

Tags: minify, uglifyjs, uglifyjs2

Is there a way to tell UglifyJS to skip a particular section of code, perhaps using comments like this:

```
// uglifyjs:skipStart
filter = function(item){ /* some crazy filter logic that will repeat 500,000 times */ }
// uglifyjs:skipEnd
```

My use case has to do with avoiding the minification of a function that will be inlined and parsed in a custom way for performance gain. Minification breaks the simplified parser.

Comment: Smartaleck answer: use coffeescript :) But serious, nope, haven't.

Comment: still looking for a solution too. @SimplGy, did you find anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is not a way to do this.

Answer (score -1):

The Global Definitions of Uglify Compressor is a feature you can use in order to conditionally drop code.

```
    global_defs: {
      DEBUG: false
    }
```

the compressor will assume that's a constant defintion and will discard code like this as being unreachable:

```
    if (DEBUG) {
      ...
    }
```

http://lisperator.net/uglifyjs/compress